# Is there a way to disable all PrimeFaces animations?

Tags: jsf, animation, primefaces

I know I can disable the animations in every component, for example:

```
<p:selectOneMenu effect="none">...
```

But this way I would have to do it manually for every component... Is there a way to do this only once an apply it for every component which supports animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nevermind, just found out that primefaces is based upon jquery UI. And searching for "disable all animations in jquery ui" i found this solution:
Just execute this javascript in the bottom of the load order:

```
$.fx.off = true;
```